# Why does nothing happen after instantiation? (C++ memory allocator implementation)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, allocator

This is quite a strange assignment for a C++ course that I recently got. The idea is to implement a simple memory allocator in C++ using a doubly-linked list. My C++ is only limited to solving problems on Codeforces, so I have no idea why nothing seems to get printed. Here's the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tests.h"

int main() {
    Tests tests = Tests();
    tests.run();

    return 0;
}
```

**allocator.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "allocator.h"

void* CleverPtr::get() const {
    return data;
}

Allocator::Allocator() {

    Allocator(100);//100 Bite
}

Allocator::Allocator(size_t size) {

    memory = (char*)malloc(size);

    head->next = nullptr;
    head->prev = nullptr;
    head->size = size;
    head->block = memory;
    head->state = FREE;
}

CleverPtr Allocator::alloc(size_t size) {

    dl_l *ptr = head;
    bool find = false;

    while (ptr){
        if (ptr->state == FREE and ptr->size >= size) {
            find = true;
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    if (find) {
        dl_l new_block;
        new_block.next = nullptr;
        new_block.prev = nullptr;
        new_block.block = ptr->block;
        new_block.size = size;
        new_block.state = OCCUPIED;

        ptr->block = (char*)((uintptr_t)(ptr->block) + size);

        add_to_list(ptr->prev, &new_block, ptr);

        return CleverPtr(new_block.block);
    }

    return CleverPtr(nullptr);
}
void Allocator::free(CleverPtr &ptr) {
    dl_l * node = (dl_l*)((char *)ptr.get() - offsetof(dl_l, block));

    node->state = FREE;
}

void Allocator::defrag() {
    dl_l *ptr = head;

    while(ptr) {
        if (ptr->next) {
            if (ptr->state == FREE and ptr->next->state == FREE) {
                ptr->size += ptr->next->size;
                remove_from_list(ptr->next);
            }
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

std::list<dl_l*> Allocator::show_busy_blocks() const {
    dl_l *ptr = head;

    std::list<dl_l*> busy_blocks = std::list<dl_l*>();

    while(ptr) {
        if (ptr->state == OCCUPIED) {
            busy_blocks.push_back(ptr);
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return busy_blocks;
}

std::list<dl_l*> Allocator::show_free_blocks() const {
    dl_l *ptr = head;

    std::list<dl_l*> free_blocks = std::list<dl_l*>();

    while(ptr) {
        if (ptr->state == FREE) {
            free_blocks.push_back(ptr);
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return free_blocks;
}
```

**tests.cpp**

```
#include <cassert>
#include "tests.h"


void Tests::run() {

    Allocator allocator = Allocator(100);

    //CleverPtr ptr = allocator.alloc(10);

    //std::list<dl_l*> busy_blocks = allocator.show_busy_blocks();

    //assert(busy_blocks.size()==1);
    cout << "Test 1" << endl;

    //CleverPtr ptr1 = allocator.alloc(10);
   // std::list<dl_l*> busy_blocks1 = allocator.show_busy_blocks();
    //assert(busy_blocks1.size()==2);
    cout << "Test 2" << endl;

   // CleverPtr ptr2 = allocator.alloc(10);
   // std::list<dl_l*> busy_blocks2 = allocator.show_busy_blocks();
    //assert(busy_blocks2.size()==3);
    cout << "Test 3" << endl;

   // allocator.free(ptr1);
    //std::list<dl_l*> free_blocks = allocator.show_free_blocks();
    //assert(free_blocks.size()==2);
    cout << "Test 4" << endl;

    //allocator.free(ptr2);
    //std::list<dl_l*> free_blocks1 = allocator.show_free_blocks();
   // assert(free_blocks1.size()==3);
    cout << "Test 5" << endl;

    //allocator.defrag();
    //std::list<dl_l*> free_blocks2 = allocator.show_free_blocks();
    //assert(free_blocks1.size()==1);
    cout << "Test 6" << endl;

    cout << "Tests done successfully" << endl;
}
```

**allocator.h**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdio>
#include "dl_list.h"

#ifndef ALLOCATORLT_ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATORLT_ALLOCATOR_H

typedef struct{
    int* offset;
    int size;
} block;

using namespace std;

class CleverPtr {
    void* data;

public:
    void* get() const;
    explicit CleverPtr(void* data): data(data){}
};

class Allocator {
    private:
        char* memory;
        dl_l* head;



    public:
        Allocator();
        explicit Allocator(size_t size);

        std::list<dl_l*> show_busy_blocks() const;
        std::list<dl_l*> show_free_blocks() const;

        CleverPtr alloc(size_t size);
        void free(CleverPtr&);
        void defrag();
};


#endif //ALLOCATORLT_ALLOCATOR_H
```

**dl_list.h**

```
#include <cstdint>

#ifndef ALLOCATORLT_LIST_H
#define ALLOCATORLT_LIST_H

#endif //ALLOCATORLT_LIST_H
enum STATES {FREE, OCCUPIED};

typedef struct dl_list {
    struct dl_list *next;
    struct dl_list *prev;
    int size;
    char * block;
    int state;
} dl_l;

static void add_to_list(dl_l *prev_node, dl_l *new_node, dl_l *next_node) {
    if (prev_node) {
        prev_node->next = new_node;
        new_node->prev = prev_node;
    }

    if (next_node) {
        next_node->prev = new_node;
        new_node->next = next_node;
    }
}

static void remove_from_list(dl_l *node) {
    if (node->prev)
        node->prev->next = node->next;

    if (node->next)
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
}
```

**tests.h**

```
#include "allocator.h"

#ifndef ALLOCATORLT_TESTS_H
#define ALLOCATORLT_TESTS_H


class Tests {

public:
    void run();
};


#endif //ALLOCATORLT_TESTS_H
```

I had to insert all the code so that the issue can be replicated. As you can see, I commented out all the lines of code in `tests.cpp` since they have no effect on the output anyway.

All the `cout`s after the `Allocator allocator = Allocator(100);` line are ignored, which means that something is wrong with that constructor call. I have no idea what exactly, though.

Can someone please help me out with that?

P.S. If you happen to notice any other bugs or severe mistakes (I suspect there are some), please let me know. Thanks

Comment: `Allocator::Allocator() { Allocator(100); }` won't do what you expect it to do: It creates a temporary that is destroyed immediately after leaving the constructor – and leaves your constructed object uninitialised. You most likely wanted constructor delegation instead: `Allocator() : Allocator(100) { }`

Comment: `Allocator::Allocator` dereferences the `head` pointer without initializing it.

Comment: *If you happen to notice any other bugs or severe mistakes* Well, unless this is a typo `Allocator::Allocator() { Allocator(100); }`, this should never have been written if you're going to do something advanced like create an allocator.

Comment: `dl_l new_block; /* ... */ add_to_list(ptr->prev, &new_block, ptr);` – you add a pointer to a local variable, which will get destroyed on exiting the function – leaving a dangling pointer inside your list...

Comment: By the way, this is not Java. You don't need to do `Test t = Test();` all the time, just writing `Test t;` will already create a new, valid object, calling the default constructor. Similarly, you can pass parameters to: `Allocator a(100);`

Comment: @OP -- Why do I get the impression that you're writing C++ by attempting to use another language (Java maybe) as a guide?  That never works out ok.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, your impression is spot on. The closest to C++ I had to work with was C#. And even that exposure was very brief. For the most part, I use Python.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to `typedef` a C++ `struct` to be able to use it.

Comment: Where did you get that dl_list from anyway? In C++, there's already `std::list`, which implements that already – and with clean C++ interface, so usage is *much* simpler *and* safer...

Comment: If I understood the assignment correctly, we need to use a custom doubly-linked list interface and then implement a free-list allocator. Based on my experience with C++, imagine what I felt when I heard that :)

Comment: This dl_list seems to be a C implementation. There are some impacts then, but they don't seem to apply here, as you can create all your nodes from C++ via `new`. I assume that you are not allowed to modify dl_list, so you'll probably have to live with not having constructors and destructors available...

Comment: To avoid memory leaks, make sure that once you don't need a node any more you delete it again. That's something you don't have to care for in python or C#, but C++ doesn't come with a garbage collector!

Comment: Your `alloc` looks pretty strange to me. You *do* find a node with sufficient space and create a new one in consequence? Wouldn't you rather use the one just found and only create a new one if there wasn't one free? And only return null if creation failed?

Answer (score 1):

You never assign `head` a value, yet you dereference it in the constructor with `head->next = nullptr;`. Most likely, head is `NULL` or points to garbage, causing a fault when you try to access the `next` pointer.

Look at this code:

```
Allocator::Allocator(size_t size) {

    memory = (char*)malloc(size);

    head->next = nullptr;
    head->prev = nullptr;
    head->size = size;
    head->block = memory;
    head->state = FREE;
}
```

You haven't set `head` to point to anything at all. What do you think `head->next` is here?

I suspect you meant this:

```
Allocator::Allocator(size_t size) {
    head = NULL;
}
```

There's no reason to allocate a block here since nothing wants a pointer to one.

Comment: That's undefined behaviour, malloc does not produce a valid object, so you'd actually need do a placement new before using it.

Comment: Better would be writing a constructor for `dl_list` and set members there. Then all we'd need would be `head = new dl_list();`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, can you please elaborate a bit more in your answer. I added the `head = NULL` line, but there is still no output.

Comment: @DonDraper With `head = NULL` followed by `head->next = ...` you don't use uninitialised pointer any more, but dereference a null pointer – still leading to crash. If you want to set the next/prev pointers, you need a valid object, so create one...

Comment: @Aconcagua, must be a stupid question, but do you mean I should instantiate a dl_list object first?

Comment: @DonDraper Of course. Objects don't appear just out of nothing. But don't use local variables, as in `alloc`, that will get destroyed again after exiting constructor!

Comment: @Aconcagua, `head = new dl_list()`, is that the right way?

Comment: @DonDraper Yes but you need to define a constructor for `dl_list` beforehand (that will initialize the members properly). Then you will be able to write `head = new dl_list;` safely.

Comment: @Fareanor Well, there's an implicit default constructor, it won't initialise the members, but as this is done afterwards anyway, that won't be a tragedy...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes of course, but it would be safer to initialize pointers members to `nullptr` explicitly.

Comment: @After adding `head = new dl_list()`, I get Assertion Error at the first assert-statement. That must an implementation error then?

Comment: @Fareanor Agree (see comments of mine above). But if looking at dl_list.h, it looks pretty much like being designed for C. Well, I don't consider it a good idea to intermix C and C++ that closely anyway...

Comment: @DonDraper You mean you uncommented that again? That might be a consequence of the local variable pushed into your list as dangling pointer (see comment to question). Maybe the value got overwritten already and the block isn't seen as occupied any more. Actually, *anything* could happen, as you introduced undefined behaviour already that way...

Comment: Why are you trying to allocate a block in the constructor? Nobody is asking for a block. Do you just want to start with one free block for some reason? If so, why not call the code that allocates a block rather than repeating the logic?

Comment: The idea, at least the way I see it, is to first allocate a contiguous block of memory (with malloc) and then do free/defrag/realloc etc. That said, my understanding of the logic might be totally wrong. Hence, all the issues and bugs.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. The code seems to be quite thoroughly busted then, I mean dozens of bugs. Why does `Allocator::Allocator` allocate an extra allocator? Why does `Allocator::alloc` store the address of an object that immediately goes away? Why does `Allocator::alloc` not modify the block it found leaving it on the list?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I guess that answering those questions requires much more knowledge of C++ than I currently have. So, unless asking to spoon-feed the bugs and workarounds to me is an option, I will have to take some time learning C++ to get a proper understanding.